# react + redux - 401 - unauthorized - missing headers in Request Headers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, authorization, redux-saga

```
return fetch(`{SERVICE API URL}`, {
  method: 'GET',        
  headers: {
    'userName': "username",
    'password': "password",
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(reddit, json)))
```

I'm trying to get service API data with authorization headers, but getting 401 - Unauthorized error and the response is **Missing Request Headers**.

Tried with sending authorization content with body also - getting same error 401 - Unauthorized error.

**Edited:**

[image]

```
 headers: {
        'userName': "xyz",
        'sessionToken': "xyz................."
      }
```

When I'm checking with Postman client it is working fine, **but not with the redux-saga fetch method**. Kindly help me for this.

Comment: seems like a typo in actual code.. can you confirm??

Comment: Worth trying `credentials: 'same-origin'`.

Comment: Do you have access to the Backend code? If it's Yes, then what language do you use for backend?

Comment: Yes, I'm having backend code - JAX-RS. but I don't know java still I can try...

Comment: have you tried lowercase 'username' and 'sessiontoken' keys rather than 'userName' and 'sessionToken'?

Comment: yes, I've tried

Comment: I think that request is about OPTIONS method. It's basically asking the server if the request is okay. See at the Access-Control-Request-*. It means the server need to authorize that headers.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's a backend problem - **CORS Filter configuration**

If the backend is on a different server (could be on the same machine, but in a different Application Server, in other words, on a different port) you have to do some CORS Filters configurations.

The frontend code is running on a server - that means it's an application. Postman is a client, just like Google Chrome or any other browser. That's the explanation why you can do the request without any problem from Postman but unsuccessful from your frontend application.

I guess you enabled the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header on the backend

Now you have to **allow your custom headers** with [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)

Comment: Seems also plausible to me. Postman is doing a post request whereas the actual fetch request gets blocked.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I use `fetch` and I need to add `headers` to the request I do it this way:

```
headers: new Headers({
  Accept: 'application/json',
  Authorization: token,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}),
```

so you might want to try this approach, also in order to debug this issue you might want to check your `Netowrk` tab and verify which headers are sent with the request.

Comment: Tried, but not working. Getting the same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Check the API documentation, the error suggests that you are not providing the right headers. Also have you checked the network tab in the dev tools to make sure your headers are passed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `Authorization` bearer header.

For instance:

```
headers = new Headers({
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${authorizationCodeOrCredentials}`
});
```

In your code:

```
return fetch(`{SERVICE API URL}`, {
  method: 'GET',        
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + someValue, // Add this line
    'userName': "username",
    'password': "password",
    'content-type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(reddit, json)))
```

Comment: My services expecting sessionToken and Username only, even I tried to send the Authorization, still it is not working... getting 401

Comment: Did you try changing `userName` to `username`? Case sensitivity matters in some cases depending on how your server parses things. Also, it doesn't look like you are sending the sessiontoken, either. Your server is specifically looking for `username` and `sessiontoken`, not `userName`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux system & If you have chrome in it...

Run your chrome using following command

> /opt/google/chrome/chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

Try now, If everything works fine then it's **CORS** issue from Backend.